# What methods should I use to soften or remove my accent?

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent, accent

https://voca.ro/1jeSBpuxHA4c

I've had a weird journey learning English. Having grown up in Canada, I learned English before I learned my own native language. Once I moved back to the country from which my parents are originally from, my Canadian accent was totally lost. I moved back to Canada two years ago and have been having difficulty with my accent. I have attempted to learn how to pronounce all vowels and constants and I have also tried shadowing but I am still far from a native English speaker.

https://voca.ro/1kHNEYCwH5HW

Comment: This is an off-topic question for ELL.

Comment: Give yourself more credit: your accent is not bad at all! I couldn't disagree more with @Kentaro's comment: I had no trouble at all understanding you. Now, of course there are things you could improve, but I hope you don't feel like your accent is a major obstacle to communication. It isn't, at least to my ear.

Comment: It's not off topic at all. When did the pronunciation of English become off topic? I'm not a native speaker unlike @TypelA so that I said cruel thing but coming out like this deserved at least a vote. (IMO).

Comment: I can HARDLY hear you.

Comment: @Lambie Turn your volume up. That's a technical issue, not a linguistic issue. (Yes, the recording is quiet.)

Comment: No, it is still not loud enough. He speaks in such a low-toned voice it makes it difficult to grasp his accent *well*. It's almost a whisper. Ali: rerecord it and speak louder.

Comment: @Kentaro wrote "it is very difficult to catch even a word". Nonsense. Possibly spiteful. Ali, you speak very clearly. I do agree with Lambie, though. You are speaking like you are in church, and in a bit of a monotone. You need to 'produce' your voice more, but there is nothing wrong with either your accent or pronunciation. You do not sound like a native speaker (although I can hear Canada) but if you are remaining in Canada just stay with it. Practice conversation, watch TV news (especially interviews with members of the public).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Nah...his voice is too low how many times I listen to.

Comment: ugm I am sorry, closed for opinion based? Where the heck is the opinion thing..

Comment: @MichaelHarvey My intention was to record it again, but the thread was closed since the content was opinion based. Nevertheless, I have previously recorded something for another website. The audio quality is also a little poor due to my microphone, but it's a lot better than this one. https://voca.ro/1kHNEYCwH5HW

Comment: @Lambie Here's another link. https://vocaroo.com/1kHNEYCwH5HW Is it better? The audio quality is a bit poor too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts, in no particular order. I can't really offer any strong suggestions on what you should focus on first or what's most important, but here are the things I noticed after listening.

- You over-enunciate some consonants, and under-enunciate others. Your /t/s are sometimes [*too* crisp and sharp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping). On the other hand your /d/ in "understand" is almost inaudible.
- You seem to muddle through some words, like when you say "like, is it my rhythm ..." this should be six distinct syllables, but the /ɪ/s seem to disappear and the consonants blend together.
- Some of your vowel tones and lengths are off. (On the other hand, some of them are perfect.) Example: the /ʌ/ ("uhh" sound) in "... something [else]?" is too deep and too long. This is the kind of nuance that can take decades to master, and many people beyond a certain age simply never can. That's okay! I'm a foreign language learner & expatriate myself, and I've accepted the fact that I'll very probably never master nuances like this and will always have an "American accent."

Give yourself more credit: your accent is not bad at all! I couldn't disagree more with the comment saying you were hard to understand: I had no trouble at all understanding you. Now, of course there are things you could improve, but I hope you don't feel like your accent is a major obstacle to communication. It isn't, at least to my ear!

Comment: Even though the sound ain't great, I feel that you are going overboard here.

Comment: @Lambie Can you expand on that? Do you think this person doesn't deserve an answer for some reason, that the points I raised are incorrect, or that the explanations need improvement? I'm happy to incorporate constructive feedback.